# Canada Visa stamping in US

Tags: visas, canada, vfs-global

I got my Canada visitor visa approved in the United States. I received a letter to send my passport. I did my biometrics in Texas.
I want to know what type of money order/ Cashier's check I have to send. I tried to chat with VFS, they told me that I have to pay the following fees in one money order:

- Package transmission $22.80
- One way Courier $37.20
- SMS optional $2.50 USD

Do I have to make the money order for **$62.50** and put it in the envelope? Also, where do I get this money order or check in the United States?
Which courier service shall I use: UPS, USPS or FedEx?

I received the following letter:
[image]
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Who (or what entity) sent the letter? What was its text? It would be helpful insert the letter text into your question (using the "Edit" button below the question text, after removing  personal ID info (your name, address, passport type, passport number, etc).

Comment: Nothing else? Who or what entity sent the letter? Business or governmental letters usually include entity names and return addresses.

Comment: I have added the complete letter, other than this, it is just my personal information!

Comment: So... have you read the instructions on that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read and follow the directions in the email and on the linked page.

The email you received from Immigration, Refugees, and Citizenship Canada (a department of the Canadian national government) contains a web link. Go to the linked page, and enter your Canadian Immigration UCI (Unique Client Identification) number. Doing so should result in the display of a specific mailing or courier address to which you will send your passport.

You must meet the passport requirements set out in the letter. The passport must:

> - Have at least one blank page
> - Be valid for the duration of your expected stay in Canada

In addition:

> - Along with your passport, you must also include a copy of the letter itself
> - Visas can only be issued for a term up to the passport's date of expiration

In the United States, you can purchase a money order at a bank, a credit union, or a United States Post Office.

Comment: and any 7/11...